# LXDhost doesn't report packages to landscape in container

Tags: 18.04, server, landscape, lxd, container

Good day fellas,
I have landscape running in a lxd container. Containers are in bridge mode. I added the lxdhost to landscape, which worked fine and it connects normally as far as I can tell. However it does not report it's packages, which makes it pretty useless for patchmanagement as you can imagine. All systems are running ubuntu 18.04. If I ran the landscape-package-reporter manually, I get the following error:

```
sudo landscape-package-reporter 
[sudo] password for lxcuser: 
2020-01-17 14:38:53,220 ERROR    [MainThread] None
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 653, in _runCallbacks
current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/landscape/client/package/reporter.py", line 92, in <lambda>
result.addCallback(lambda x: self.request_unknown_hashes())
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/landscape/client/package/reporter.py", line 498, in request_unknown_hashes
self._facade.ensure_channels_reloaded()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/landscape/lib/apt/package/facade.py", line 265, in ensure_channels_reloaded
self.reload_channels()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/landscape/lib/apt/package/facade.py", line 253, in reload_channels
version, with_info=False).get_hash()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/landscape/lib/apt/package/facade.py", line 402, in get_package_skeleton
return build_skeleton_apt(pkg, with_info=with_info, with_unicode=True)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/landscape/lib/apt/package/skeleton.py", line 131, in build_skeleton_apt
version.record, "Provides", DEB_PROVIDES))
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/package.py", line 690, in record
return Record(self._records.record)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 724: invalid start byte
```

Funnily enough all the other containers report normally their packages, no problems whatsoever.

I looked in to the scripts but as my programming knowledge is pretty low, I couldn't find what the issue may be.

Maybe one of you has an idea.

Edit from 2023: It seems like Veeam fixed it on their side. I'm on 22.04 now and landscape 23.03 and it works without doing any customisations.

Comment: I would advise checking the logs in `/var/log/landscape/package-reporter.log` instead of running things manually. That log (which could be different from the log files) seem to indicate something wrong with text encoding. I'd recommend checking that your locales are properly configured by checking `env`, possibly re-running `dpkg-reconfigure locales` and restarting the landscape-client service. I've seen misconfigured locales in the past (usually noticed by perl warnings) on a few images and/or when using `lxc exec`.

Comment: I followed your advice and took a look at the log. It had the same error though. After that I checked my locales and made them the same as on the containers which means that LANG=C.UTF8. Unfortunately I still get the same error. I copied the files that make errors from a working container, but that didn't change anything either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue (specifically the one at position `724`) is related to a stray unicode character in the Veeam package list, `/var/lib/apt/lists/repository.veeam.com_backup_linux_agent_dpkg_debian_public_dists_stable_veeam_binary-amd64_Packages`. I discovered this

We have reported this issue to Veeam, so it might or might not get fixed soon (I will update this post).

The easy (but non-permanent way) is to delete the stray character at the end of `/var/lib/apt/lists/repository.veeam.com_backup_linux_agent_dpkg_debian_public_dists_stable_veeam_binary-amd64_Packages`. However, this change will get overwritten when `apt` updates the `veeam` package list.

The permanent solution (which will only be overwritten by a `launchpad-client` update) is to add a `try`/`except UnicodeError` block around the relevant code in `skeleton.py`

See [my blogpost](https://techoverflow.net/2020/04/17/how-to-fix-landscape-package-reporter-unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte/) for more details on how to do that.

Comment: Thanks a dozen, that did it!